# In Google Chrome Version 81.0.4044.122 Desktop, how do I block video autoplay on a random website

Tags: google-chrome, video

It is annoying and time-wasting to manually pause or close all the autoplay videos on a random website that I visit using Google Chrome Desktop Version 81.0.4044.122 from windows 10.

> How do I turn off the autoplay feature in Google chrome Desktop?

I am not looking for extensions but an inherent browser feature.
I looked up the `Settings` --- `privacy and security` --- `Site Settings` but wasn't successful for the cause.

Comment: Did you check the chrome flags ?

Comment: @pjmg Nothing useful came up on flags' search *autoplay* or *video*.